# Smartest way to square root of 64b in FPGA

Tags: integer, signal-processing, verilog, fpga, square-root

I can find a lot of algorithms for doing square roots (or estimates) of integers in FPGAs for 8 and 16 bits, but I have a 64 bit value and I cannot seem to find a good solution to this.

Is there a good method for the square root of an unsigned 64bit value? (I am wiring in Verilog on a Xilinx part in Vivado if that matters)

--Edit--
I should add that I will be performing this calculation every clock on a new value, so a set number of iterations will be best so I know which output is coming out.

Comment: Do you want the fastest way, or the smartest?

Comment: @Nick Good question, I guess that is a tradeoff.  If you mean the smartest is the slickest, that doesn't bother me.  I guess which ever one is the best with resources and has a predictable number of cycles.

Comment: Search online for various examples of efficient squareroot computaitons. The wikipedia article has a great example when you're dealing with floating point numbers, and there are whole stack Q&As devoted to the question of `sqrt` in embedded contexts. FPGAs give you tremendous degrees of freedom, and obviously the advice to do this in the most FPGA-y way possible would be to design circuits that implement one of these fast methods to a decent approximation. There are also methods that are assisted by lookup tables, requiring some bytes of what mounts to ROM storage.

Comment: All recommendations are conditional on your specific use-case, existing data format and/or interop requirements (why 64 bit int?), precision requirements, ability to program the FPGA, etc. I'm not sure what you mean by "every clock", but obviously you're constrained by whatever rate that is, and need to fly below that radar, making accuracy tradeoffs accordingly. A fair bit of numerical analysis needs to go into ensuring the properties of your implementation are somewhat stable, and that there aren't "bad inputs" which will produce greater deviations than you can reasonably work with.

Comment: @toozie21: So you want to compute the 32-bit integer square root of a 64-bit integer, and are not seeking to compute the square root of a 64-bit fixed-point number, e.g. in a 32.32 fixed-point format? I am wondering what kind of signal-processing would require 64-bit operands, given that most sensors provide a resolution of 16 bits or less. Are you sure you need the full 64 bits?

Comment: Our PoC-Library's sqrt module [PoC.arith.sqrt](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_sqrt.vhdl) can compute any N-bit square root in (N+1)/2 cycles. It's possible to rewrite it to a pipelined version.

Comment: Since it wasn't mentioned before, you could take a look at the CORDIC algorithm (its also an IP core in Xilinx CoreGen).

Comment: Thanks to all. I originally had floating point, but I scaled up to 32b signed ints to try to make the math easier in the FPGA (but I am starting to wonder if that saved me anything). CORDIC only allows up to 48b input for sqrt, but I'll look into some of the other suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest, and probably best-optimized way of doing this is letting someone else do that – Xilinx has an IP core that can do that; it's the [LogiCore CORDIC](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/cordic_ds249.pdf).

You might also want to look at logarithm implementations (e.g. log2, or anything that converts your fixed point number to floating point); Sylvain Munaut [wrote one](https://github.com/EttusResearch/fpga/blob/rfnoc-devel/usrp3/lib/rfnoc/fosphor/f15_logpwr.v#L215); applying basic math, using the logarithm *log_b* to the base *b*:

*sqrt(x) = b^(log_b(x)/2) = b^(y/2) = b^z*

You could do the *y/2* operation with a DSP slice, or just by bitshift. *2^z* is a bit more tricky, but in reality it boils down to shifting `0b10` by the integral part of *z*, and multiplying that with a looked-up version of *2* to the power of the fractional part.

If you can live with being really inaccurate, how about just roughly approximating the *log_2* of a number by the position of the highest non-zero binary digit, and then using a lookup table to convert to a square root.

Assuming you can do the finding of the highest digit in two cycles, and the lookup and output generation in the next, you'd have a three cycle implementation; it'd still be very sensible to pipeline this instead of building a humongous mux chain.

Comment: ty for the response.  I planned to use CORDIC, but my version (Vivado 2015.2) does not allow for an input of >48b.  I am not currently working in fixed point, but in integer.  I basically have two 32b floats coming in, but wanted to simplify the math, so I scale to ints between [-2^16,2^16] and tried to do all my math based on that. In the end I was trying to do an abs val of a complex number, hence the sqrt (I am using CORDIC for the squaring of the Re and Im parts). I am sure I am over thinking things, so I will take a look at Sylvain's work.

Comment: "two 32bit floats" are **not** worth one 64bit int

Comment: @toozie21 If you are trying to do the abs value of a complex number you should use the CORDIC to do a rectangular to polar conversion. The Re and Im are your rectangular coordinates, and you just need the magnitude of the polar coordinates and you can throw away the phase.

Comment: @nguthrie just a comment to avoid confusing people that read this later on: I'm pretty sure what you say is right for fixed point, but nonsensical nonsensical for float; abs(z) = sqrt(Im(z)²+Re(z)² ) in float is pretty simple if you have something that can add up two floats; squaring/rooting floats is relatively doable.. However, on FPGAs you usually don't use floats, so I'm not quite sure what OP is *actually* considering to do.

Comment: THanks guys, been out of the loop a bit, but still looking into all of this.  I have the option of floats vs fixed and am pretty sure that I've convinced myself that the only way to have any chance of success with my build is to stick in the fixed world. I will have to look at the CORDIC rect to polar conversion, I didn't know about that.